# lodash.get Returns Null Always in Vue.js

Tags: arrays, vue.js, foreach, null, lodash

So I'm using the Vue.JS computed call on a constant variable to pull info from a PUSH API, as such:

```
const configList = computed(() =>
   lodash.get(store.state.socket, 'configList', null) // returns array(1)
)
const statusList = computed(() =>
   lodash.get(store.state.socket, 'statusList', null) // object
)
```

I'm trying to use it in a different computed variable (or in any instance, really), but it always seems to be a gamble? I will have the following executed below:

```
const test = computed(() => {
    let merge = []
    if(statusList){
       let mergeList = {
         id: configList.value[0].id,
         name: configList.value[0].name
         error: statusList.value.error
       }
    merge.push(mergeList)
    }
    return merge
})
```

And sometimes it will return an error "Cannot read properties of null" for configList, sometimes its for statusList, when they both exist and are fully populated?

I'll even console.log(configList), and it will display as such:

```
_value: null
value: Array(1)
```

For reference: configList should be returning an array with a length of 1, and statusList is just returning an object with multiple true/false checks; specific values from both are merged into an array, and then returned to populate a Vue.JS DataTable.

What I've tried:
Setting configList to a separate variable, and then attempting to access, such as:

```
let config = configList.value[0]
```

Putting `configList.value.forEach(element => {})` before mergeList and etc., it seems to work and the data is populated, but I still get a massive console error that claims "Cannot read null properties (reading 'forEach)", as well as two vue.js warnings about "error during execution of render function" and "scheduler flush"

Thanks for any suggestions, not sure why this is happening.

Comment: You're making two asynchronous API calls, but not confirming that both have returned data when you try working with them.  "sometimes it will return an error "Cannot read properties of null" for configList" That is happening when the `statusList` API call returns before the `configList` call  has returned.

Comment: (`if(statusList && configList) {...}` might be enough to get you there.)

Comment: Seems to have done the trick, although I haven't tested it much? I had attempted that earlier and it didn't work, but everything is fine now